# Is it possible to cover an $11 \times 12$ rectangle with $19$ rectangles of $1 \times 6$ or $1 \times 7$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, coloring, tiling

> Is it possible to cover an $11 \times 12$ rectangle with $19$ rectangles of $1 \times 6$ or $1 \times 7$?

**Attempt:**

There should be $132$ unit squares to be covered. Since there are $19$ rectangles to be used, let $x$ be the number of $1 \times 6$ rectangles and $19-x$ be the number of $1 \times 7$ rectangles. The solution of
$$ (19-x)7 + (x)6 = 132 $$
is
$$ 133-7x + 6x = 132 \implies x = 1$$

So there should be only $1$ rectangle of $1 \times 6$, and $18$ rectangles of $1 \times 7$.

Now color the $132$ unit squares black and white like a chessboard, the top left is black..then its right is white...then its right is black again.. and so on.

Odd rows should be
$$ [black]-[white]-[black]- ... -[black]-[white]-[black] $$
Even rows is 
should be
$$ [white]-[black]-[white]- ... -[black]-[white]-[black] $$

For a $1 \times 6$ rectangle, it will definitely cover $3$ blacks and $3$ whites.

For a $1 \times 7$ rectangle, it will either cover $4$ blacks and $3$ whites, or cover $3$ blacks and $4$ whites. Let the number of $4$ blacks-$3$ whites coverings be $y$, and $18-y$ for the other one.

Notice that in total we must have $66$ blacks and $66$ whites. So in total there will be 
$$ |black \: squares| = 3 + 4y + 3(18-y) = 57 + y \implies y = 9$$
$$ |white \: squares| = 3 + 3y + 4(18-y) = 75 - y \implies y = 9$$

So there should be $9$ rectangles that cover $4$ blacks-$3$ whites, and $9$ rectangles that cover $3$ blacks- $4$ whites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\matrix{\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0\\0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0\\0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0\\0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0\\0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1\\0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0\\0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0\\\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0\\0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0\\0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0\\0,0,0,\color{red}1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\color{red}1,0} $$

We have $20$ red cells and $19$ rectangles. Each rectangle can cover at most $1$ red cell. So..

Comment: Not very deep, yet elegant :-)

Comment: This is really nice approach and I also upvoted but shouldn't one also consider what the remaining pieces are? For instance if we have two $1 \times 3$ rectangles instead of a $1 \times 6$ rectangle, we can cover the board although we have $19$ rectangles and $20$ red cells.

Comment: @ArsenBerk wouldn't that be 20 rectangles then?

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. I had to say a $2 \times 3$ rectangle instead of two $1 \times 3$ rectangles. But in that case, since it could cover two red cells, that wouldn't be a problem so don't mind my question at all :D

Answer (score 5):

Same as @Aqua's answer but I made a pretty image:

[image]

No two rectangles can cover more than one red square, so you need at least $20$ rectangles to cover all red squares.